# Impossible to get NULL from empty value in pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In my table "Group" I have not a name=John,so I want to get the NULL value in "new_name".

```
SELECT name INTO new_name FROM Group WHERE name="John";
```

in pl/sql:

```
if(new_name IS NULL) then  ---here is the problem,I can't enter in "if",instead of having name=NULL, I have name=" ",and when I try to use if(new_name=" "), there's an error....---
     some code .....
end if;
```

so how to check in "if" satement, is it NULL or not(no need to use EXISTS)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't have NULL but a space; if that's what you are saying, then you should enclose it into single quotes:

```
if new_name = ' ' then ...
```

**However**: back to beginning. If there's no row whose `name = 'John'`, then `select` won't return `null` but raise the `no_data_found` exception which you should handle, somehow.

One option is to actually "handle" it:

```
begin
  begin
    select name into new_name from group where name = 'John';
  exception
    when no_data_found then new_name := null;
  end;

  if new_name is null then
     some code ...
  end if;
end;
```

Or, if you use an aggregate, you'll avoid the exception handling section (which means "less typing", but it kind of *hides* what's going on):

```
begin
  select max(name) into new_name from group where name = 'John';

  if new_name is null then 
     some code ...
  end if;
end;
```

I suggest you handle it properly.

Answer (score 2):

A simple method is to use aggregation:

```
SELECT MAX(name) INTO new_name
FROM Group 
WHERE name = 'John';
```

An aggregation query with no `GROUP BY` is guaranteed to return one row.  If all rows are filtered out, then the results of the aggregations are `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

your IF condition should be fine but like Littlefoot mentioned, your logic will never satisfy your If condition since the NAME will always be not NULL.

You can use NVL() too if you want to assign values in your new_name variable other than NULL then use that in your IF condition.